# Not Able to update Filter data results in cursor adapter which is in a fragment in android

Tags: java, android

I am unable to update the filter results in cursor adapter. Below is my code.

oneFragment.java

```
 public void searchInDb(String value) {
        cAdapter3.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

            @Override
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                String searchValue = constraint.toString();
                MySql dbHelper = new MySql(context, "mydb", null, HomeScreen.dBversion);
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                cursor3 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM remindertbNew where SUBJECT=" + "'" + searchValue + "'", null);
                Log.d("CursorCount","" + cursor3.getCount());
                return cursor3;
            }
        });

        cAdapter3.getFilter().filter(value);
        cAdapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I am doing query and calling the above function in tabviewActivity. Below is my code:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.one_item, menu);
        Date date = new Date();
        String startTime = CommonUtils.getTimeFormatInISO(date);
        if(CommonUtils.getDate(startTime).equals(dateForActionBar)) {
            restoreActionBar("Today "+ dateForActionBar);
        }
        else {
            if(dateForActionBar != null && !dateForActionBar.equals("")) {
                restoreActionBar(dateForActionBar);
            }
            else {
                restoreActionBar("Appointments");
            }
        }
        MenuItem delete = menu.findItem(R.id.deleteIcon);
        delete.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fa_appointment));
        delete.setVisible(true);

        //search Menu Item Added To Appointmentlist
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)
                getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchAppointment);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.
                getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                if(oneFragment != null) {
                    **oneFragment.searchInDb(query);**
                }

                Log.d("SerchFunction", query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                //todo: check the Adapter  :::
                if(newText != null) {
                    Log.d("SerchFunction", newText);
                   // searchInDb(newText);
                    if(oneFragment != null) {
                        **oneFragment.searchInDb(newText);**
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: Provide adapter class

Comment: inside `onQueryTextChange` call `adapter.getFilter().filter(newText)`

Comment: pskink,Thanks for wring in. i have tried that. am getting the new cursor data but Am not able to set the new cursor to Adapter. after filter Listview showing old  cursor data only.

Comment: Ganesh pokale.. Thanks for wring in.

Comment: This is my cursorAdapter Class.

Comment: public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context,  Cursor c, int flags) {
       super(context, c,flags);
       this.context = context;
       this.cursor = c;
       inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
               Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

Comment: public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor){
        final int dbid = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        ImageView button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.reminder_icon);
        TextView time = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.time);
        TextView toName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNo);

Comment: if(toname != null && !toname.equals("")) {
            toName.setText(toname);
        }

Comment: @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reminder_list_item, parent, false);
        this.cursor = cursor;
        bindView(view, context, cursor);
        return view;
    }

Comment: call `setFilterQueryProvider` only once, then call `adapter.getFilter().filter(newText)` as i said before